# How to Use lm function in r.net?

Tags: c#, .net, r

I need to use Regression (Linear) in my application for that i am using R.Net.but when i am using the function lm() it's showing an error "Error in the application." but the same code will working in "R" is there any problem with my code or do i need to import any more packages?...

my code

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        REngine.SetDllDirectory(@"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.1\bin\i386");            
        REngine engine = REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet");
        engine.Evaluate("WQ<-read.csv('c:\\Documents and Settings\\hardinmvarghese\\Desktop\\reg.csv')");
        engine.EagerEvaluate("rst <- lm(V1 ~ V2+V3+V4+V5,WQ)");

    }
```

if any one knows this please help me...

Comment: Do you have read/write rights on that directory from .Net? Use a try catch block and check

Comment: Which line does the code fall over on?  Is the `REngine` instance successfully being created?  Can you run other R commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have read/write rights on that directory from .Net? Use a try catch block and check the Exception type and Message. Maybe its not something thats wrong the the REngine code.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        REngine.SetDllDirectory(@"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.1\bin\i386");            
        REngine engine = REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet");
        engine.Evaluate("WQ<-read.csv('c:\\Documents and Settings\\hardinmvarghese\\Desktop\\reg.csv')");
        engine.EagerEvaluate("rst <- lm(V1 ~ V2+V3+V4+V5,WQ)");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.GetType().ToString() + " " + ex.Message);
    }

}
```