# C# - linear regression on deedle Series

Tags: c#, linear-regression, deedle

I have built a deedle series of type:

```
Series<DateTime, double>
```

within a C# solution. I am trying to perform a linear regression (still within this solution) using the R function 'lm' (its syntax is lm(y~x, data) where y is the response and x the predictor)

```
 public static void performLinearRegression(Series<DateTime, double> series)
 {
 }
```

I would be grateful if someone could help me doing that - if that's possible! I guess I have to use RProvider.RInterop.callFunc but I haven't managed to do so.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is an F# example on the R provider page showing [how to call the `lm` function](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/FSharpRProvider/Statistics-QuickStart.html), but this is using the R type provider which is, sadly, not supported by C#. When calling R from C#, you probably do not gain much from referencing the R provider, so you'll need to rewrite the sample directly using R.NET.

There is an example showing how to call `lm` in [How to Use lm function in r.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970544/how-to-use-lm-function-in-r-net) This saves the data to disk, but you really just need to create a data frame (like the F# sample does) that the function can access - and creating data frames is covered in [Creating a Data.Frame using R.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288861/creating-a-data-frame-using-r-net).

So, I think if you put those two together, you should be able to do this - Deedle sadly won't help you much here, because the nice R type provider support it has is F#-only.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks Tomas for your help.

So I have implemented the following method in C#.

```
public static Tuple<double, double, double> performLinearRegression(Series<double, double> series)
{
    REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
    REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();
    engine.Initialize();

    var x = engine.CreateNumericVector(series.Keys);
    var y = engine.CreateNumericVector(series.Values);
    engine.SetSymbol("x", x);
    engine.SetSymbol("y", y);
    var result = engine.Evaluate("lm(y~x)");
    engine.SetSymbol("result", result);

    var coefficients = result.AsList()["coefficients"].AsNumeric().ToList();
    double r2 = engine.Evaluate("summary(result)").AsList()["r.squared"].AsNumeric().ToList()[0];
    double intercept = coefficients[0];
    double slope = coefficients[1];

    return Tuple.Create(intercept, slope, r2);
}
```

where I only referenced RDotNet.

I have also implemented an F# by simply adding an F# project (FSharpInterop) to my C# solution:

```
namespace FSharpInterop

open System
open RDotNet
open RProvider
open RProvider.graphics
open RProvider.stats
open System.Linq

module myRProvider =

let performLinearRegression X Y =
let dataset =
    namedParams [
        "Y", box Y;
        "X", box X; ]
    |> R.data_frame
let result = R.lm(formula = "Y~X", data = dataset)
let coefficients = result.AsList().["coefficients"].AsNumeric().ToList()
let r2=R.summary(result).AsList().["r.squared"].AsNumeric().ToList().[0]
let inter=coefficients.[0]
let slope=coefficients.[1]
(inter, slope, r2)
```

Now, referencing FSharpInterop in my ConsoleApplication, I can do the following:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Series<double, double> series= //get a series

    Tuple<double, double, double> deedleRes = myRProvider.performLinearRegression(series.Keys, series.Values);
    Tuple<double, double, double> rDotNetRes=performLinearRegression(series);
}
```

I have the feeling it is "quick and dirty" (especially because of the way I format the results into a Tuple while I guess there are better ways to get the results in a .Net type easily thanks to Deedle) but at least it should get me going.

If you have any comments or suggestions, feel free to let me know.